# Changing element places in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a native jQuery function to switch elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698301/is-there-a-native-jquery-function-to-switch-elements)

I have list of items in my HTML, I want to change places of first and last element, but how can I do that with jQuery? I can get first and last elements, but how can I change their places (order) in list?

Example HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="item-1">1</li>
    <li id="item-2">2</li>
    <li id="item-3">3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var first = $("ul li:first");
var last = $("ul li:last");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
first.appendTo(first.parent());
last.prependTo(last.parent());
```

Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KxJN/)

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('#item-1').after($('#item-3'));
 $('#item-2').after($('#item-1'));
```

Comment: `$('#item-1').after($('#item-3'));`

Comment: but not worked for me :)

Comment: ah - sorry I misread your answer - you are quite correct. My bad typo :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this question [Is there a native jQuery function to switch elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/698301/569659)