# jquery swap content between two DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two span tags. I'd like to swap the content between them once the user clicks on one of them. If the user clicks once more, swap the content again and so on.

```
$(".sectionTitleText").livequery("click", function () {
        var editor = $(this).attr("data-edit-id");
        var viewer = $(this).attr("data-view-id");

        //Swap code
});
```

Comment: Yep, sounds like a plan.

Comment: What's the source of `//Swap code` ??

Comment: @jnpcl I rather think that's what he's asking for help with!

Comment: @Alnitak: You mean, asking us to do for him?

Comment: Yes, they are siblings. I thought there was a function in JQuery to swap the content I did not know of.

Comment: Yeah what is livejquery? You don't just mean `live` do you?

Comment: @tou - please show the markup - if there's only two children in that parent the answer could be trivial...

Comment: No, livequery is a plugin to which does the same thing as live, but also for elements gotten through AJAX. There are several items of this in the page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a native jQuery function to switch elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698301/is-there-a-native-jquery-function-to-switch-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".sectionTitleText").livequery("click", function () {
        var editor = $("#span1");  //put your ids here
        var viewer = $("#span2");

        editorContent = editor.clone();
    viewerContent = viewer.clone();

    editor.replaceWith(viewerContent);
    viewer.replaceWith(editorContent);
});
```

Comment: Is there a swap method in JQuery ?

Answer (score 4):

If both nodes are the only children of the same parent, just do this:

```
$('#parent').prepend($('#parent').children().last());
```

This should take whichever element is currently last, and make it first.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/wt4VZ/ for demo.

If that doesn't apply, try:

```
var el1 = $('#element1');
var el2 = $('#element2');
var tag1 = $('<span/>').insertBefore(el1); // drop a marker in place
var tag2 = $('<span/>').insertBefore(el2); // drop a marker in place
tag1.replaceWith(el2);
tag2.replaceWith(el1);
```

The idea here is that the two temporary spans just act as place holders into which the original elements will be dropped, *without serialising or otherwise messing with those elements*.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/bzKXn/ for a demo of that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic jQuery function to do it:

```
$.fn.swapWith = function(swap_with_selector) {
    var el1 = this;
    var el2 = $(swap_with_selector);

    if ( el1.length === 0 || el2.length === 0 )
        return;

    var el2_content = el2.html();
    el2.html(el1.html());
    el1.html(el2_content);
};
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/7gV2s/2/) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple content swapping.

```
var temp = $("#span1").html();
$("#span1").html($("#span2").html());
$("#span2").html(temp);
```

Comment: not a good idea IMHO to serialise and deserialise the elements when there are perfectly good DOM methods which will move them directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need too keep the text in the span :

```
var firstText = $('#first_span_id').text()
var secondText = $('#second_span_id').text()
```

and then swap it :

```
$('#first_span_id').text(secondText)
$('#second_span_id').text(firstText)
```

If your span contains html tags, you may want to use **.html()** instead of **.text()**

Comment: not a good idea IMHO to serialise and deserialise the elements when there are perfectly good DOM methods which will move them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what livequery is, but what about this:

```
function swapEditView(){
    var temp = $('#data-edit-id').html();
    $('#data-edit-id').html($('#data-view-id').html());
    $('#data-view-id').html(temp);
}

$('#data-edit-id').click(function(){
    swapEditView();
});

$('#data-view-id').click(function(){
    swapEditView();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp object :

```
$element1 = $("#selector1");
$element2 = $("#selector2");

var $temp = $("<div>");
$element2.after($temp);
$element1.after($element2);
$temp.after($element1);
$temp.remove();
```

It's possible with before() too.
It's possible because after() and before() move (or add) object in DOM, not duplicate it.