# Completely cut and paste an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I cut (completely, with all styles and attributes) an element from a location and paste it in another location (like `body`) with jQuery?

Also, I want to place a string (or tag) in the old location, because I want to change its place to old location at the end of the script.

Can I?
How?

Comment: Ive never heard of anything like this but maybe create an event handler for a copy command, (plenty of examples on google, then just remove the inner html, you will have to save the inner html code somewhere first, before pasting it. Maybe in xml or other methods. May be the object can only be cut when a paste has already been chosen, then you could do it all in one function. Dont think its impossible thought heres how to detect copy and paste events http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-detect-copy-paste-and-cut-behavior-with-jquery/

Comment: Note: Elegant solution to swap 2 neighboring items: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8638127/669677

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) will automatically move the matched elements from their current location to the specified container, which seems to be what you want.

You can use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert new content before moving the element:

```
$("#yourElement").after("<p>Element was there</p>").appendTo("body");
```

Comment: +1 but if the CSS is applied like this though `.someContainer #yourElement { color: blue; }` taking it out of the container will "ruin" the style. So it might be more complicated.

Comment: Thank you. i was using `appendTo()` but I didn't know it will move elements.

Comment: @kikio, unfortunately, unless the new container also exposes the `someContainer` class, the styles will indeed change. To my knowledge, there's no easy way to compute and reapply the original styles. Maybe you can change the CSS rules so the appropriate styles will apply to the element regardless of its container?

Comment: yes, "I" can, but i'm developing a plugin, maybe my users can't

Answer (score 26):

[`.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) is more appropriate for this task, as @lvan suggested.

```
jQuery(jQuery("#yourElement").detach()).appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 8):

you can do it by clone 
first copy it to another location

```
$('#yourElement').clone().appendTo('#anotherDiv');
```

then remove old one,

```
 $('#parentOfOldElement #yourElement').remove();
```

or you can replace it to get it later

```
  $('#parentOfOldElement #yourElement').replaceWith('<div id="toReplaceAgain">/div>');
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm newbie in jQuery, and didn't heard about `remove()`

Comment: `.detach()` could be used instead of `clone()` and `remove()`

Answer (score 1):

`insertAfter()` and `insertBefore()` are exactly cut and paste methods.

Answer (score 1):

unless or untill you are not cloning any element all operator will move the selected element from one location to other ex: appendChild , appendTo , insertAfter , insertBefore and so on