# How to mutually replace (change) 2 div nodes in DOM with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have two node references in variables nodeA and nodeB. I would like to mutually replace them with each other in DOM, keeping their all attributes and attached event handlers etc.

How can I accomplish this with jQuery? 
I tried .replaceWith(...) but as I see it works with html text, and I would like to keep the DOM object itself.

There will be two .replaceWith(...) call. And the second one is on a node, which is not in the DOM... It seems not working...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `replaceWith` works fine with jQuery objects too.

Comment: `replaceWith` is correct. It will remove them from the DOM and insert the new content in its place with a single call.

Comment: There will be two .replaceWith(...) call. And the second one is on a node, which is not in the DOM...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: switch Elements in DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034918/jquery-switch-elements-in-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be simmilar as switch variables, but you need to think it in terms of DOM.

```
var temp = $('<div>'); 
temp.insertAfter(first);
first.insertAfter(second);
second.insertAfter(temp);
temp.remove();
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qsutQ/

Answer (score 1):

Using a function from this answer:

[jquery: switch Elements in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034918/jquery-switch-elements-in-dom)

```
function swapElements(elm1, elm2) {
    var parent1, next1,
        parent2, next2;

    parent1 = elm1.parentNode;
    next1   = elm1.nextSibling;
    parent2 = elm2.parentNode;
    next2   = elm2.nextSibling;

    parent1.insertBefore(elm2, next1);
    parent2.insertBefore(elm1, next2);
}
```

Switching should be pretty simple and doesn't require creating any temporary elements:

```
swapElements($("#obj1")[0], $("#obj2")[0]);
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/JvAMq/1/
(Click on the text to see alert boxes, the event bindings hold)