# Possible to swap position of div elements using CSS?

Tags: html, css

In my example there are two div, I just wanted that first div come down after second div using css
let suppose below example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1" >

This is first div.
</div>
<div class="div2" >
    This is second div.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code give output like below

This is first div.

This is second div.

but i wanted output should be

This is second div.

This is first div.

Don't use margin top:20px because text in mycase will bigger then in example.

Comment: We cannot understand what you are asking for without some code

Comment: Why not change the HTML to have the `div` with `class="div2"` first? KEEP IT SIMPLE!

Comment: i can modify that content of project but can add CSS file to the project, so thats why asking this type of question

Comment: can you use position: absolute?

Comment: @user2431786 are you able to access the javascript? -- if so you can swap it after page loads but it would be ugly and noticeable on slower connections

Comment: cann't use jquery or javascript @Gustonez and with postion absolute u have to set margin which is not best way when text of div changes dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Just use a table. You must work on three elements, a container and the two containing elements.

```css
#container {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
#first{
     display:table-footer-group;
 }

#second{
     display:table-header-group;
 }
```

```html
<div id ="container">
    <div id = "first">This is the first div</div>
    <div id = "second">This is the second div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Both the below are pure CSS, and support any number of items without requiring alteration to display properties.

Using [**flex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), [**flex-flow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) and [**order**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order):

### [Example1: Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m37cxb9g/)

```
    body {
        display:flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    .div1 {
        order:2;
    }
    .div2 {
        order:1;
    }
```

Alternatively, reverse the Y scale:

### [Example2: Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnfo1m7u/)

```
body {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
div {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

Comment: @Gustonez - actually example 2 does: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform (IE9+), and example 1 does, using the `-ms-` vendor prefix

Comment: Didn't know about flex-column. Interesting answer. +1 for version 2. But version 1 - `flex-flow` is supported only in IE11, Chrome21, FF28, Opera12 and not supported in Safari, so consider not using that approach

Comment: interesting... also this may help him to understand more about flex: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by many posters, yes there are CSS options.

However if you were inclined to do so; jQuery/Javascript is also a solution.

Please see: [jquery: switch Elements in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034918/jquery-switch-elements-in-dom) if you wish to take this route.

Comment: Appears so, see @Bhargav's answer.

Comment: There are actually multiple approaches in CSS, which allow for any number of items (unlike tabulated solutions) whilst still supporting the original display properties (below)

Answer (score 0):

now for HTML and CSS from below code

```css
#example {display: table; width: 100%; }

#block-1 {display: table-footer-group; } /* Will be displayed at the bottom of the pseudo-table */
#block-2 {display: table-row-group;    } /* Will be displayed in the middle */
#block-3 {display: table-header-group; } /* Will be displayed at the top */
```

```html
<div id="example">
    <div id="block-1">First</div>
    <div id="block-2">Second</div>
    <div id="block-3">Third</div>
</div>
```

**Output**

Third
Second
First.