# Swap 2 very distant elements containing dynamic content in jQuery

Tags: jquery

If there is something like this:

```
<div id="one">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>

<div id="two">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>
```

I know you can do:

`$("#two").before($("#one"));`

But what about this situation when you have something like this:

```
<div id="one">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>

<div id="two">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>

<div id="three">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>

<div id="four">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>

<div id="five">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>

<div id="six">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>

<div id="seven">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>

<div id="eight">
  ...other elements inside...
</div>
```

and you want to swap `#eight` and `#four` how would you do that in Jquery? Each div contains a lot of code and this code is dynamically changed so only the `#one`, `#two`, etc. of the main divs are stable and callable.

Comment: .eq(index) would perhaps be useful

Comment: Create a temporary placeholder div at one location, swap that item to the other's location, then swap the other back to the placeholder, and finally remove the placeholder.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034918/jquery-switch-elements-in-dom

Comment: @Draco18s go left, forward, then turn right... anyway thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bwegs for the find. Adding for completeness.

```
function swapElements(elm1, elm2) {
    var parent1, next1,
    parent2, next2;

    parent1 = elm1.parentNode;
    next1   = elm1.nextSibling;
    parent2 = elm2.parentNode;
    next2   = elm2.nextSibling;

    parent1.insertBefore(elm2, next1);
    parent2.insertBefore(elm1, next2);
}
```

Note that it's fine if the reference element (next1 or next2 above) is null; insertBefore handles that correctly (by adding at the end of the parent, like appendChild would).