# Ordering Div External

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a html Page with a specific order, for instance:

```
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
   <div id="one"></div>
```

But i need order it, i can touch the html, so, the idea is use Javascript/Jquery to do that, is there a way to make that without touch the html?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698301/is-there-a-native-jquery-function-to-switch-elements

Comment: You mean, you need to reorder the `<div>` elements so that they are in the order "one, two, three"?

Comment: @JordanGray Exactly, i miss that part in the question, but yes, i need ordering like one, two, three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with jQuery:

```
$('#one').parent().append($('#three')).append($('#one')).append('#two');
```

this way you have, div 3, 1, 2 in that order.
You are selecting one of the divs, and selecting it's parent. then you append them at the order you want.

if you want to use pure javascript:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('one').parentNode;
parent.appendChild(document.getElementById('three'));
parent.appendChild(document.getElementById('one'));
parent.appendChild(document.getElementById('two'));
```

now, assuming you have a lot of divs, i will assume #one til #ten:
you can create an array, with the ids ordered as you wish, for example:

```
var order = ['ten', 'eight', 'six', 'four', 'two', 'nine', 'seven', 'five', 'three', 'one'];
for(var i = 0; i < order.length; i++){
    parent.appendChild(document.getElementById(order[i]));
}
```

is this what you're looking for?

Comment: thx for the answer it works, but in my case also i have some more divs ex: <div id="three">three</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="test">test</div>
<div id="tests">tests</div>
<div id="testes">testes</div> All of them are created in asp and parse in the html, the asp some time sends unordered items, so i dont know the exactly position of them, if i use the parent() to set the position some time it not will be in the correct position

Comment: so, you want an easyway to order them all?

Comment: no, parent refers to the container of those divs. can be another div or can be the body, for example

Comment: Little note, you need an extra closing parenthesis here: `parent.appendChild(document.getElementById(order[i]‸);`

Answer (score 3):

for the simple answer using .before:

```
$('#three').before('#two');
$('#two').before('#one');
```

Answer (score 1):

yes... try to use this code:

```
$('#two').appendTo($('#one').parent())
$('#three').appendTo($('#two').parent())
```

Comment: that way, you are placing them inside of each other