# move form fields up or down dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have a form field. Also I can dynamically add more fields, can I swap them by clicking on a link or button (up and down) using JS or jQuery?

Comment: `Up or down`? Care to elaborate? Show markup? Code? http://jsfiddle.net? Question? Something?

Comment: Well, I dont even now how to start, never did that, only have dynamic form

Comment: I hope you realize that *dynamic form* means like *nothing* without context/code/jsfiddle.

Comment: @setup a fiddle / show some code, be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following functions that can help in adding elements: [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add after an element, [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add before an element.

For swapping elements there's already a [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698301/is-there-a-native-jquery-function-to-switch-elements).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old-school approach (JS):
http://www.nuff-respec.com/external/javascriptgui.html