# jQuery - Swap values between select lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of *n* selects containing values from 1 to *n*. Whenever I change a value in a select, the other select containing the same value should be swapped to what was previously selected in the first select.

For example, initially *listA* is set to 1 and *listE* is set to 5. If *listA* is changed to 5 then *listE* should become 1, and the other lists remain unchanged.

This is different from questions such as [How to swap values in select lists with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008759/how-to-swap-values-in-select-lists-with-jquery) because the values are swapped between multiple dynamic lists instead of between two static lists.

**EDIT**: Every value should only appear once in the group of lists. They initially all have distinct values.

Here is the code I have so far, needless to say, it does not work :

http://jsfiddle.net/yye3U/

HTML:

```
<div class="parentdiv">
  <select class="ranking">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <select class="ranking">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <select class="ranking">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2<option>
    <option value="3" selected>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var previous;
$( ".ranking" ).on( "focus", function() {
    previous = $( this ).val();
}).change(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    var parent = $( this ).closest( ".parentdiv" );

    $( ".ranking option[value='" + value + "']", parent ).not( this ).parent().prop( 'selectedIndex', parseInt(previous) - 1 );
});
```

Comment: Not sure to understand, you mean like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/yye3U/2/

Comment: So will it always initially start as Select0[0], Select1[1], Select2[2],...,SelectN[N]?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Changing the first list to 2 then back to 1 won't update the second list when changing back to 1. Each value should only appear once in the list.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon's answer seems to be exactly what I thought you were asking for as well, I've just updated with 5 options. http://jsfiddle.net/yye3U/3/

Comment: So if you have three selects, with the order 1,2,3, and then change the third to 1, the order should be 3,2,1? If so, then what should the order be after than if the second select is changed to 1?

Comment: @j08691 That should be 3,1,2

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Ah! I just realized that is because the previous value is only changed on focus... is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Digzol i just fast coded to see if that was what you wanted, if that's a yes, ill post a good code.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon With an alternative way to the focus method this is exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By storing the previous value in the data of the DOM element, you can easily do what you want with that simple code :

```
$(".ranking").each(function(){
    $(this).data('__old', this.value);
}).change(function() {
    var $this = $(this), value = $this.val(), oldValue = $this.data('__old');

    $(".ranking").not(this).filter(function(){
        return this.value == value;
    }).val(oldValue).data('__old', oldValue);

    $this.data('__old', value)
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yye3U/6/)

Comment: This still sets two items as the same number.  If you go through and set each one to 1, and keep going up and down you can get it to stay.

(Set first to one, then second to one, then third to one, then second to one again)

Comment: @dcclassics nice catch, checking that.

Comment: Nice!  Sorry I just critiqued and didn't provide any suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just add ':selected' to your selector in the last line of your JS:

```
$(".ranking option[value='" + value + "']:selected", parent).parent().not(this).prop('selectedIndex', parseInt(previous) - 1);
```