# Swap two elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, swap

I'm trying to swap two elements using up and down arrows.

A JSFiddle solution would be great!

My HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="content">Some text</div>
    <div class="move">
        <div class="move-down">down</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="content">Some other text</div>
    <div class="move">
        <div class="move-up">up</div>
        <div class="move-down">down</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="content">Some text</div>
    <div class="move">
        <div class="move-up">up</div>
        <div class="move-down">down</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="content">Some other text</div>
    <div class="move">
        <div class="move-up">up</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My last try was:

```
// el is the clicked one.
jQuery('.move').children().click(function(el) {
    if (jQuery(el).hasClass('move-down') === true) {
        el = jQuery(el).parent().parent();
        el.prependTo(el.after(el));
    } else {
        el = jQuery(el).parent().parent();
        el.appendTo(el.before(el));
    }
});
```

I've tried a lot of different ways to change items. I've tried with `replaceWith()`, `before()`, and `after()` but nothing worked.

NOTICE:
I've already written a function which displays the correct up / down DIVs. So the first and last one can only moved in one direction. That's already solved. I also can't use any kind of existing jQuery plugins.

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: your 'el' variable is being used in two different ways here.

Comment: `el` is not the element clicked, it's the event. `this` is the element clicked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a native jQuery function to switch elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698301/is-there-a-native-jquery-function-to-switch-elements)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this - you need to check e.target not the div with class = move

```
jQuery('.move').children().click(function (e) { // <-- argument passed in is the event not an element
    var $div = $(this).closest('.item'); // get closest item div
    if (jQuery(e.target).is('.move-down')) { // check if clicked is movedown
        $div.next('.item').after($div); // if it is move after next
    } else {
        $div.prev('.item').before($div);// else move it before previous
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/Cpz5P/)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.move-down').click(function (e) {
        var self = $(this),
            item = self.parents('div.item'),
            swapWith = item.next();
        item.before(swapWith.detach());
    });
    $('.move-up').click(function (e) {
        var self = $(this),
            item = self.parents('div.item'),
            swapWith = item.prev();
        item.after(swapWith.detach());
    });
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Se4/

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
jQuery('.move > div').on('click', function(event) {
    var item = jQuery(this).closest('div.item');
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('move-down')) {
        item.prev('div.item').before(item);
    } else {
        item.next('div.item').after(item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this while I was looking for an answer to the same question:

[Is there a native jQuery function to switch elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698301/is-there-a-native-jquery-function-to-switch-elements)

```
jQuery("#element1").before(jQuery("#element2"));
or
jQuery("#element1").after(jQuery("#element2"));
```