# .insertBefore() Switch postion (HTML) between 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert

**Example HTML :**

```
<h2 class="x1">1</h2>
<h2 class="x2">2</h2>
<h2 class="x3">3</h2>
<h2 class="x4">4</h2>
<h2 class="x5">5</h2>
```

**I want to switch like...**

```
1
2 <---
3     |
4     |
5 <---
```

So I do like this

```
$('.x2').insertBefore('.x5');
$('.x5').insertBefore('.x2');
```

So I get result like this

```
1
3
4
5 <--- 
2 <---
```

**How can I get result like... ?**

```
1
5 <---
3     |
4     |
2 <---
```

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/aHwSJ/

**PS :** If possible **I dont want to do** like

```
$('.x2').insertBefore('.x5');
$('.x5').insertBefore('.x3');
```

I need to select element only 2 elements (NOT ANOTHER)

Comment: Sarting from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698301/is-there-a-native-jquery-function-to-switch-elements; something like this http://jsfiddle.net/aHwSJ/2/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a native jQuery function to switch elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/698301/218196). See bobince answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/698440/218196.

Comment: Thanks , Seems like they using .before() and .after() :D

Comment: @FelixKling I prefer Paolo Bergantino solution :-)

Comment: @Edward tell why pls ?

Comment: @Edward Yeah tested , Work in all of my case :D

Comment: Do it .... :D @Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from this good solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/698386/975520 you can made up your own jQuery function to handle the switch capabilities.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery.fn.swapWith = function(to) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var copy_to = $(to).clone(true);
        var copy_from = $(this).clone(true);
        $(to).replaceWith(copy_from);
        $(this).replaceWith(copy_to);
    });
};
```

And use it like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.x5').swapWith('.x2');
});
```

I appreciate this solution because using the [`deep clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method all bound events are preserved.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/axvp9/

Comment: I appreciate that you linked to the original question, but since this is an exact copy, you rather should have voted to close the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You want to insert `.x5` before the next sibling of `.x2`, not before `.x2` itself.

```
var next = $('.x2').next();
$('.x2').insertBefore('.x5');
$('.x5').insertBefore(next);
```

This does only work if `.x2` is not the last sibling though.

Comment: Ok , So @arun anwser can do if last silbing ?

Comment: @l2aelba: I don't know, try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var pos = $('.x2').index();
$('.x2').insertBefore('.x5');
$('.x5').insertBefore($('h2').eq(pos));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P4Dfs/1/)

The previous may not work if the order of elements changes, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P4Dfs/3/)

```
var el1 = $('.x4'), el2 = $('.x1'), el1prev = el1.prev();
el1.insertBefore(el2);
if(el1prev.length){
    el2.insertAfter(el1prev);
} else {
    el2.insertAfter($('h2').eq(0));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P4Dfs/2/)

Comment: Thanks so much :D Forgot about .index() +1 Good idea :D

Answer (score 0):

use temporary div:

```
var x2 = $('.x2');
var x5 = $('.x5');
var div =$('<div>');

x2.replaceWith(div);
x5.replaceWith(x2);
div.replaceWith(x5);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/aHwSJ/1/

HTML:

```
<h2 class="x1">1</h2> 
<h2 class="x2">2</h2> 
<h2 class="x3">3</h2> 
<h2 class="x4">4</h2> 
<h2 class="x5">5</h2>
```

code:

```
var pos = $(".x2").next();
$('.x2').insertBefore('.x5');
$('.x5').insertBefore(pos);
```