# how can I repleace two items from sortable puzzle box without pushing another pieces?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, puzzle

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#box").sortable({
    
    cursor: "grab",

  });
  
});
```

Hi I`m building a simple puzzle with sortable ui for my kid. i already have box 4x4 pieces with
16 cutted pieces of image . but problem is that sortable item pushing other elements by one to te left side on x axis when repleacing pieces from y axis . I want to one grabbing piece repleace other piece without pushing rest of the pieces in the box

this similar and shows my problem https://codepen.io/vijaykumar/pen/xLEbZE

Comment: You will need to show your code, perhaps in a working snippet, so what you are experiencing can be seen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change switch position behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747622/change-switch-position-behavior)