# Core animated pages, animate always from right

Tags: polymer

I wish to animate a page *always* from the right when switching between two pages. Why? Because the 'next' page is always dynamically loaded. Is there a neat way to do this? I am self answering with a hack, however I am looking for a way that isn't messing witht the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this effect by switching the DOM order of the elements instead of switching the `selected` property of the `<core-animated-pages>`. A way to do this can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/698440/1266242). The disadvantage is that it makes is very hard to switch between transition types (if so you were to wish) and makes for some ugly code either way.